# Deleting billions of records from Oracle Table containing trillions of records

Tags: oracle

I need to delete approx. of 30 billion of rows from an Oracle table that has about 100 + billion of rows. I have all the IDs of the rows I need to delete in a temporary table. Currently I am using single delete statement as below, also using SUBPARTITION and created Index on the temp_table. However this took 4+ hrs to complete in PRODUCTION.

```
DELETE FROM table_name SUBPARTITION(subpartition_name) WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM temp_table);
COMMIT;
```

Is there a way I can optimize this to run bit fast.

Just for a note :

1. The oracle table I am referring is common for multiple clients, so the below option is not suitable here.
   Creating new table and move the required data into it  and drop the old table followed by renaming the new table to old table.
2. Delete in Batch : Looping over the temp table and deleting something like below, is taking more time in non-prod environment, and not sure how it goes in production env.

```
DECLARE
  vCT NUMBER(38) := 0;

BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT id FROM temp_table) LOOP
    DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = t.id;
    ......
    ......
      COMMIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

3. Option to create individual DELETE statement is also not feasible here as the record count is in Billions.

I did checked, there are partitions and sub-partitions on the table which I am utilizing it, and there is **no** child table dependent on it.

Please suggest.

Comment: How are you determining which `id` values to put into the temporary table?  If this is something that needs to happen regularly, the table would normally be designed so that you can just drop one or more partitions rather than deleting 30 billion rows.

Comment: Seems to be a poor design of your partition key. Typically you drop or truncate entire (sub-)partition.

Comment: @JustinCave - I queried to the original table, and based on some conditions determined which records need to delete. So captured all the id's into temp table, so that I don't have to run the same condition again and again. Now the temp_table has all ID's which are targeted to delete from original table.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - indeed poor design, but have to live with it.

Comment: But do those conditions have some relationship to the partitioning scheme?  Or are you really deleting 30% of the data from every partition?

Comment: It sounds like this is a one-time operation.  Or at least one-time to be this massive, followed by regular housekeeping of less massive scale.  If that is the case, then it sounds like you are spending more time trying to shorten the process than the process itself is taking.

Comment: Yes.. its a one-time activity, and for future not have such bad data we already implemented a logic to delete or skip such records from inserting. Now the issue is with the existing records which is already there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete (or update) large number of rows is *pain* and take lot of time.

The most effective way to manage it is to use the [updatable join views](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/admin/managing-views-sequences-and-synonyms.html#GUID-C37E704C-AF40-42DA-85ED-372A62A74E58)

What is requested, but should be no problem is a *unique index* on your *delta* table containing the `id` to be deleted.

Also while using this approach be sure, that the **large table has no unique index on the `id` column**. *There are some technical issues if both tables have unique index on the join column* - see below.

Than use following query (if you want to use sub-partition wise) delete

```
delete from 
(
select delta.id, big.id big_id 
from delta 
join big subpartition (SYS_SUBP220880)
on delta.id = big.id  
)
```

Oracle uses the *hash join* of both tables which is in your case the only possibility to manage your scale. You may dedploy *parallel option*, do not forget to enable it.

This is the expected execution plan:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT              |       |   100K|  1757K|   875   (2)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  DELETE                       | BIG   |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                   |       |   100K|  1757K|   875   (2)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL          | DELTA |   100K|   488K|    47   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   4 |    PARTITION COMBINED ITERATOR|       |   783K|  9947K|   825   (1)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL         | BIG   |   783K|  9947K|   825   (1)| 00:00:01 |    65 |    65 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - access("DELTA"."ID"="BIG"."ID")
```

Note - in case that more than one joined tables are key preserved, see the documentation [Note on Updatable Views](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-VIEW.html#GUID-61D2D2B4-DACC-4C7C-89EB-7E50D9594D30__GUID-E5397C44-3E35-4408-BF19-20C67E545FEA)

> For a DELETE statement, if the join results in more than one key-preserved table, then Oracle Database deletes from the first table named in the FROM clause, whether or not the view was created WITH CHECK OPTION.